# SoftWire Library Programming Questions for I2C with Digital Pins

Tags: i2c, digital

I am trying to use 3 TOF10120 Laser Sensors with one Arduino that all have the same, fixed I2C Address. I don't believe it is possible to change the I2C address of the TOF10120, but if I am wrong, please let me know (also, I need 3 different addresses). This being said, I am trying to use the SoftWire Library (https://github.com/stevemarple/SoftWire - very interesting library, but not great documentation) to help me to use my three sensors with Digital Pins. Does anyone have any experience with the SoftWire Library and how to get readings from a laser sensor?

I can provide the code I have, but it probably wouldn't be very helpful anyway. I am particularly curious as to how to use the DigitalWrite() and DigitalRead() functions for I2C with SoftWire.

Thanks for all the help in advance!

Comment: you are asking questions about a sensor, but you have not provided any documentation for the sensor

Comment: The datasheet is in another language - it isn't helpful at all. The default address is 0x52 for I2C. I bought the sensor from here: https://www.amazon.com/Taidacent-100-1800mm-Distance-Infrared-Detector/dp/B07KW1XN5X

Comment: foreign language datasheet is more useful than no datasheet

Comment: Link to Datasheet PDF in Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KAIB9xDaO4HcIDBsFz9ia2koAKH_af-_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: that datasheet has enough english to find what you need ... there appears to be a command to set the I2C ID ... use google translate to confirm

Comment: Would you mind telling me on what page and in what location/line on that page that command is? Also, how do you even send the sensor the command?- any resources for doing so would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found where it is, but am unsure of exactly how to proceed. Is the command s7-xxx#? How would I even send this command to the sensor? I wouldn't think it would be via the Arduino IDE.

Comment: connect one sensor to arduino and use a sketch to send the command

Comment: You may use the SoftWire library for that. You may share the SCL lines and have one SDA line for every sensor. Look at the "ListDevices" example of the SoftWire library; you will have to create three SoftWire objects with different SDA pins. Alternative, you may use an I²C multiplexer like TCA954x (there are breakout boards available), which is more convenient as you can use the default (hardware) Wire library and save space and cycles.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the tof10120 to any i2c address between 1 and 254. you need to write the serial string 's7-xxx#' where xxx is the decimal address required (in string form). I wrote a simple python program for the raspberry pi to change my sensor addresses via the Rx Tx.

Comment: If would be good to add a reference to where that information can be found in official documentation if possible.  From what I gather the change *is* perminant, or rather non-volatile.  If that's correct, it might be good to say.